# c# MySql.Data not loading

Tags: c#, mysql, c#-4.0

```
using System;
using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;
namespace Input
{
    class MainClass
    {
        public static void Main (string[] args)
        {
            string connectionString = "server=SQL09.FREEMYSQL.NET;database=m44m31;uid=m44m31;pwd=*******"; 
            MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(connectionString);
            try
            {
                conn.Open();
            }
            catch
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Failed to connect");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

there is my code and here is the error i keep getting...i'm using mono on ubuntu:

```
Unhandled Exception: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'MySql.Data, Version=6.5.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d' or one of its dependencies.
File name: 'MySql.Data, Version=6.5.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d'
[ERROR] FATAL UNHANDLED EXCEPTION: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'MySql.Data, Version=6.5.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d' or one of its dependencies.
File name: 'MySql.Data, Version=6.5.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d'
```

i really don't know what to do and have searched every where, please help!

```
    [assembly: AssemblyVersion ("6.5.5.0")]
[assembly: InternalsVisibleTo ("MySql.Data.Tests, PublicKey = 0024000004800000940000000602000000240000525341310004000001000100d973bda91f71752c78294126974a41a08643168271f65fc0fb3cd45f658da01fbca75ac74067d18e7afbf1467d7a519ce0248b13719717281bb4ddd4ecd71a580dfe0912dfc3690b1d24c7e1975bf7eed90e4ab14e10501eedf763bff8ac204f955c9c15c2cf4ebf6563d8320b6ea8d1ea3807623141f4b81ae30a6c886b3ee1")]
[assembly: AssemblyConfiguration ("")]
[assembly: AssemblyKeyName ("ConnectorNet")]
[assembly: InternalsVisibleTo ("MySql.Data.CF.Tests, PublicKey = 0024000004800000940000000602000000240000525341310004000001000100d973bda91f71752c78294126974a41a08643168271f65fc0fb3cd45f658da01fbca75ac74067d18e7afbf1467d7a519ce0248b13719717281bb4ddd4ecd71a580dfe0912dfc3690b1d24c7e1975bf7eed90e4ab14e10501eedf763bff8ac204f955c9c15c2cf4ebf6563d8320b6ea8d1ea3807623141f4b81ae30a6c886b3ee1")]
[assembly: InternalsVisibleTo ("MySql.Data.Entity, PublicKey = 0024000004800000940000000602000000240000525341310004000001000100d973bda91f71752c78294126974a41a08643168271f65fc0fb3cd45f658da01fbca75ac74067d18e7afbf1467d7a519ce0248b13719717281bb4ddd4ecd71a580dfe0912dfc3690b1d24c7e1975bf7eed90e4ab14e10501eedf763bff8ac204f955c9c15c2cf4ebf6563d8320b6ea8d1ea3807623141f4b81ae30a6c886b3ee1")]
[assembly: Debuggable (DebuggableAttribute.DebuggingModes.IgnoreSymbolStoreSequencePoints)]
[assembly: CompilationRelaxations (8)]
[assembly: RuntimeCompatibility (WrapNonExceptionThrows = true)]
[assembly: TargetFramework (".NETFramework,Version=v4.0", FrameworkDisplayName = ".NET Framework 4")]
[assembly: AssemblyDescription ("ADO.Net driver for MySQL")]
[assembly: AssemblyCompany ("Oracle")]
[assembly: AssemblyProduct ("")]
[assembly: AssemblyCopyright ("Copyright © 2004, 2010, Oracle and/or its affiliates. All rights reserved.")]
[assembly: AssemblyTrademark ("")]
[assembly: ComVisible (false)]
[assembly: CLSCompliant (false)]
[assembly: AssemblyTitle ("MySql.Data.dll")]
[assembly: AllowPartiallyTrustedCallers ]
[assembly: SecurityRules (SecurityRuleSet.Level1)]
[assembly: AssemblyDelaySign (false)]
```

It is added to the assembly ^^^^

Comment: Check your database name, it is missing the file type extension...

Comment: Your confusing me...explain?

Comment: database=m44m31     This is database name, right?? So it has to be an extension.

Comment: i mean like .sdf, .mdf and like so....Hope you got it this time

Comment: You don't need an extension on the db name.

Comment: You beat me too that comment lol

Comment: @BhushanFirake The problem is obviously not in the existence or non-existence of the database; it seems the compiler is not finding the `MySQL.Data` assembly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that you have a broken reference to the MySql.Data dll. Verify that the .csproj file contains the reference to the correct dll and that the dll exists in the proper location. Please post more info if this doesn't fix your problem!

Comment: its added as a reference and i don't think its corrupted...i downloaded it from the official MySQL website...what other info do you need?

Comment: Yes it does, What other info do you need?

Comment: Did you do an MD5 on the download? (I had a corrupted download at one time).

Comment: i'm going to re-download and see if it helps

Comment: Do an MD5 when you do just to be sure.

Comment: 6.6.4 is the version i downloaded

Comment: Don't know what else it could be :/ I'm using the same connector without such difficulties but in Windows. Sorry.

Comment: Did you try removing the reference and re-adding? Does the error now show the version of the `MySQL.Data` assembly as 6.6.4?

Comment: I have tried that already and it shows the correct version number.

Comment: I feel really silly asking, but you're using the .NET/Mono version of the connector, not the Windows one, right?

Comment: Yes I am, first thing I checked before downloading xD